# Batch file to copy a file at random to another folder

Tags: batch, script

I need a batch file:

Given folder A containing `.txt` files; e.g.,

```
C:\A\a.txt
C:\A\b.txt
C:\A\c.txt
C:\A\d.txt
```

and folder B (which is empty),
I need the batch script to copy one randomly chosen file from folder A to folder B
each time I run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by [this post](http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=150), your script could look like this

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set source=c:\A
set target=c:\B

set count=0
set x=0

:: put all the files into a pseudo-array prefixed with "TXT_"
for /r "%source%" %%a in (*.txt) do (
    set TXT_!count!=%%~a
    set /a count+=1
)

:: Use the 'modulo' function to get a usable value from system variable %random%
set /a x="%random% %% count"

:: Pull the relevant item out of the "TXT_" 'array'
set chosen=!TXT_%x%!

echo:I chose :: %chosen%
copy /y "%chosen%" "%target%" 1>nul
endlocal
```

This assumes that you have a moderate number of files in your source folder.
Otherwise, the number of variables in your environment might grow too big.